# Unable to follow steps for building application in Linux Os?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora

I was using these steps to build an application from [Csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) but the problem is, they have mentioned it's for Linux and I tried, as a first step:

```
subversion git quilt unzip wget swig2.0 python make
```

I get a `command not found` error. First thing is, that I'm using fedora 13. I searched for the swig, python, quilt, subversion packages in package management system in fedora already but I didn't get to install it. Can anyone help me, solving this error?

Comment: before voting down , please tell me the reason as a comment n do it so that i cannot repeat it .

Comment: I did not vote you down, but please take a little more care on spelling (There are browser dicts) and use the layout tags, which are effective here, not something else. The FAQ has hints, the edit field has buttons which have tooltiptexts, and there is a preview below the textfield. Thanks and welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a list of the programs you NEED to have installed in order to compile Csipsimple. It is not a command, and it will give an error.

Use your package management system from Fedora and install all those programs and the Android SDK as required on the page you linked to, than continue with the "Check out source code" section and the rest of the documentation.

Comment: Those packages are not available in Package management system in fedora ,i searched already .I already installed  android ndk & sdk .

Comment: Search again, they are very common Linux applications. I am sure they are in the repositories. Try installing them from console with 'yum' like: 'yum install subversion' then 'yum install git', etc. Also check that you have your repositories correctly set up.

Comment: ok i will try as u said , one more thing is that how to connect those all file as per the steps given in Link means i need to know how to link up all after indivisual installation

Comment: run "yum -y install subversion git quilt unzip wget swig python make" as root

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by 'link up all', tell at least the paragraph from the documentation you are referring to.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm Hey thanks ur commands works!!!!

Comment: @Rizvan, his command is the same as mine, written on a single line.

Comment: i dont know who voted down but there is nothing wrong i asked ? they need to see it

Answer (score -1):

Otherwise to install the  packages, you can use the command:             apt-get install subversion git quilt unzip wget swig2.0 python make yasm

Comment: The original question discusses Fedora, your solution uses apt-get (which is for Debian or Debian-derived distributions generally).